# Passing a full `event` object in Enzyme simulate function

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm currently testing a React `TextArea` component with Jest and Enzyme. This component is basically just a wrapper to a native `<textarea>` element. Its behavior is that it automatically adjusts its height depending on its current value with respect to the set `max-height`. This is the onchange event handler:

```
handleInputChange = e => {
    const { onChange } = this.props;
    const field = e.target;

    field.style.height = 'inherit';
    field.style.height = `${field.scrollHeight}px`;

    const max = parseInt(
      window.getComputedStyle(field).getPropertyValue('max-height'),
      10
    );

    field.style.overflowY = max < field.scrollHeight ? 'scroll' : 'hidden';

    if (onChange) {
      onChange(e);
    }
};
```

I want to write a unit test for it so I can test whether it did update its height or not. I've already done some research on how to simulate an onchange event to an input but what I've seen so far is it can be done by passing a "partially filled" `event` object (it only has a value attribute) like this:

```
const spy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), 'handleInputChange');
const controlledTextArea = findByTestAttr(wrapper, 'controlledTextArea');
controlledTextArea.simulate('change', {
   target: {
     value: 'This is just for test'
   }
});
```

But this will result to an error because I need to access the `style` attribute of the `e.target`.

So my question is, how do I simulate an onchange event as if there were a normal event object. I was hoping I could do something like:

```
controlledTextArea.simulate('change', 'This is another test text');
```

and then it automatically creates the `event` object for me. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way achieving that. Moreover `jest` uses [`jsdom`](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom) under the hood. And it does not implement all the API browsers have.
Also when you test your component in isolutation `getComputedStyle` will not have access to all original CSS so will return nothing.

Summing up all above you have to mock both `target.style` and `window.getComputedStyle`. Probably something alike:

```
const target = {
  value: "change",
  style: {},
  scrollHeight: 1000,
};
jest.spyOn(window, 'getComputedStyle').mockImplementation((el) => {
  if (el === target) {
    return {
      "max-height": 200,
      getPropertyValue(propName) {
        return this[propName];
      }
    };
  }
});

yourWrapper.onChange({ target });
expect(target.style.overflowY).toEqual('scroll');
```